# Better way to use dictionary for deduplicate?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary

I get big set of data that contains multiple duplicated rows. 
I want to use a dictionary to do deduplication, then insert the data into DB.

The `row.key` can NOT be set as DB Primary key. So, I can not use "DB Primary key fail to duplicate".

Process will be million rows.

I get two plans, which you think is faster?

Plan A:

```
try 
{
    dictionary.add(row);
    insert into DB
}
catch
{}
```

Plan B:

```
if( ! dictionary.containskey(row.key) )
{
      dictionary.add(row);
      insert into DB
}
```

Then what if i use multi-threading for the process. That will be multiple threads accessing the same block. Will that be safe and efficient?

Comment: `Dictionary.Add()` (or maybe the indexer) shouldn't throw when you add a duplicate key.

Comment: B will will most likely be faster, because usually exception handling is slower.

Comment: It also depends on your situation. If you expect 1% duplicates then method A is faster, if you expect 500% duplicates then B is faster.

Comment: @millimoose See exception "An element with the same key already exists ...": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @millimoose `Dictionary.Add` will throw an exception if a duplicate is added, but using the indexer will either add or replace, but not throw an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `HashSet<T>`. it's `Add` method returns a bool indicating the item is already in it or not.

```
if(hashSet.Add(row.key))
{
      insert into DB
}
```

Comment: Was just about to add this same comment. HashSet<T> will be faster than either of the original proposed solutions because it uses no exceptions and would only use one lookup per value.

Answer (score 10):

First, you don't have a key/value relationship here, so a set, rather than a map, is appropriate.  You should be using `HashSet` rather than a `Dictionary` to keep track of the key.

Next, lookups into a hash-based structure are very fast, and most importantly, *are not dependent on the size of the collection.  A lookup into a 1 million item HashSet is as fast as lookup up a 5 item set.  That constant value is almost certainly faster than relying on an exception being thrown.

Finally, the `Add` method of a `HashSet` indicates whether or not the item is added, so you're not even doing any additional lookups at all.

Beyond that, using exceptions for control flow, in addition to being poor performance, is also bad practice.  You should use exceptions for truly exceptional situations for the sake of code clarity.

Comment: There is a sort of key/value relationship here, because his items' uniqueness is based on the `.key` property of each row. So to use a HashSet, you'd need to implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<>`. Also, `Dictionary` is hash-based, so it would have roughly the same performance as `HashSet`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior While a key/value relatinoship exists, it's not used by this structure.  He never needs to get the value (a db row) associated with a key (the primary key of the table).  As for needing a custom comparer, that depends on what the primary key is.  If it's, say, an `int`, or a `long`, or a `string`, then no, he doesn't need to.  If it's several fields, he can use a `Tuple`, again avoiding the need for a custom comparer.  The point is the whole row doesn't go into the `HashSet`, just the primary key.

Comment: That makes sense, now that I see that you're talking about adding the *key* instead of adding the *row*. A code sample would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Plan B should be faster because you don't actually have to catch an exception.  In general, Plan B is also better style, since a duplicate key isn't really an 'exception', it's expected.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is faster, but you should use HashSet, something like this:

```
HashSet<string> hash = new HashSet<string>();
if(!hash.Contains(row.key))
{
   hash.Add(row.key);
   insert into DB
}
```

Comment: Thanks for actually providing a code sample to clarify how you'd use a HashSet.